# Header Problem in multiple authentication

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am trying to have multiple users: 
1. manager 
2. employee

but I am having an issue as:
ErrorException thrown with message "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"

Stacktrace:

## 4 ErrorException in E:\xamp\htdocs\TMS\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php:341

## 3 header in E:\xamp\htdocs\TMS\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php:341

## 2 Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response:sendHeaders in E:\xamp\htdocs\TMS\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php:375

## 1 Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response:send in E:\xamp\htdocs\TMS\public\index.php:58

## 0 require_once in E:\xamp\htdocs\TMS\server.php:21

my LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function redirectTo( ) {
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'manager') {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    else {
        return redirect('/employee/index');
    }
}

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

my manager.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;

class Manager
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
   function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'manager') {
        return redirest('/home');
    }

    else {
        return redirect('/employee/index');
    }
}
}
```

my employee.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;

class Employee
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
   function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'employee') {
        return redirect('/employee/index');
    }

    else {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method redirectTo should return an url path:

```
/*
LoginController.php
*/
protected function redirectTo( ) {
   if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'manager') {
      return '/home';
   }else {
      return '/employee/index';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , and after adding your suggestion, i got This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
 as errors
can you help me out ?